# Discord.py read list

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py

I have a file with a list called wbanned.txt which contains forbidden words.
I want every message sent to be read and if it contains one of the forbidden words in the txt list (Every word is on a new line from list) to be deleted.

I tried something but all it does is delete it only if it contains the last word in the list.

The code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        file = open('./resources/wbanned.txt')
        all_lines = file.readlines()
        for x in range(len(all_lines)):
            if all_lines[x] in message.content:
                await message.delete()

    except Forbidden:
        pass
```

The list:

```
word
banned
kick
```

So the program must accept this sentence: "This is example 1"
But if you type: "This a banned member" this sentence need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.readlines()` includes the trailing newlines, so you need to `.strip()` them.

Code(with some cleanup for best practices):

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        with open('./resources/wbanned.txt') as file:
            for line in file:
                if line.strip() in message.content:
                    await message.delete()

    except Forbidden:
        pass
```

(Directly iterating over a file iterates line by line the same way `.readlines()` does, but without creating an unnecessary list)

Comment: You shouldn't open the file on each message... Ideal case would be to load the file on startup and pass the list of words as a variable...